# Keyboard combination to insert non keyboard characters

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode

on windows one could with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+235 print ë into (any) textfield. I tried the same on linux and it seems to be not working. Depending on the application the result is different, but never the wanted one.

Is there a similiar combination on linux available?

Comment: google about compose key, for example <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> gives ë.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To activate the compose key I had to activate it:

1 System Settings > Keyboard
2 On Tab Typing > Layout Settings
3 On Tab Layouts > Options > Compose key

A useful list of compose key combinations can be found [here](http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html).

Comment: Your way isn't common. Common way is to setup compose key in xorg.conf or do it by setxkbmap, for example: `setxkbmap  -option ',compose:rwin'`.

Comment: Does setting it through my way have any impact? Like not working across all applications, or something like this?

Comment: No, but your way is very distro-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then input Unicode hex value. Accept with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 235 decimal is 0xeb so: <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then input <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Works as well. But this isn't as convenient as the other method (brain and hand). Its cumbersome to press the key combination, convert my decimal into a hex and then type it with the other hand.